# Can a HTTP server receive HTTPS request (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-ipn

I was reading the Paypal documentation about how to implement an IPN server to receive payment notification (from Paypal POST requests), but I noticed that the requests are in encrypted with HTTPS, and I would like to implement the server with non-secured HTTP. Is there any issue if I do this? Can I use any library that use HTTPS over a non-secured server?

Comment: Of course it can't. Final sentence is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot receive an https request with an http server.  It won't connect.  For starters, it won't even be on the right port by default and even if you try to force the correct port, an https request won't connect to an http server.

Instead, you can use an https server in your node.js app as explained [here in the nodejs https module](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html).

> Can a HTTP server receive HTTPS request (node.js)?

No, it cannot.

> Is there any issue if I do this?

Yes, it will not connect.

> Can I use any library that use HTTPS over a non-secured server?

No, you cannot.  https connections will not connect to an http server.

---

All payment related stuff should be done over a properly secured https connection so even if you could change the client to use http instead of https, you should not do that and, I'd guess that PayPal prevents that either with their client library or by license because the last thing they want is people implementing PayPal payments over insecure connections.

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Comment: I know, I was waiting for another answer :)